# Change NDT matching TF transform frame in Autoware

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Autoware 1.14 in ROS Melodic, installed from source and built with CUDA.
I want to use the lidar localizer algorithms with my ROS system that contains another autonomous car package.

Specifically, my system's TF tree is as follows: `map -> odom -> base_footprint -> base_link ->the rest of the TF frames`.

When I am using the NDT Matching algorithm, it provides a transform `map -> base_link` and it changes completely my TF tree and several other functionalities.

So, I thought to change the NDT algorithms's (matching and mapping) source code, so that they provide a transform from `map` to `odom` instead of `base_link`.

Does this sound correct? Or is there any other way to make this work?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359704/change-ndt-matching-tf-transform-frame-in-autoware/) by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 210 on 2020-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to solve this problem, I made the lidar_localizer nodes totally independent from the rest of the Autoware packages.
It is important to have the `odom --> base_link` transform, which is provided by Gazebo, another simulator or the robot itself. So, changing the source code to publish from `map --> odom`, another change needs to be made.
Before publishing the transform, you should subtract the `odom-->base_link` from `map-->base_link` which is calculated by the code and then publish its result as `map-->odom`.

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2020-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1